# assembler code in a c program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
 typedef int (FuncPtr)();
 char asmFunc[] = {0x90, 0xB8, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3};
 FuncPtr *cFunc = malloc(7);
 memmove(cFunc, asmFunc, 7);
 int result = cFunc();
 printf("result = %d\n", result);
}
```

Would be awesome if somebody could fix the assembler part on a intel i7 pc because it result in a segfault on my ubuntu :)

Is this the best way to put assembler code in a c program?

Comment: Though I cannot say if your opcodes are correct, I know it might crash for other reasons too.  Do you know if the memory that you've allocated can be used to execute code?  Usually what you get with `malloc` cannot be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way to put assembly code in a C source file would be to use inline assembly.  Here's a good [starting point](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html).  Example:

```
int main(void)
{
 int x = 10, y;

 asm ("movl %1, %%eax;"
      "movl %%eax, %0;"
  :"=r"(y) /* y is output operand */
  :"r"(x)  /* x is input operand */
  :"%eax"); /* %eax is clobbered register */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write it without the typedef but casts to function pointers without typedef are very ugly.

```
int (*testFuncPtr)(void);
```

Casting to this function pointer would be done using

```
(int (*)(void))
```

Comment: You don't have to dereference the function pointer to call the function. Today's compilers are smart enough to do that on their own - so you can simply call `testFuncPtr();`

Comment: ok thx i updated the code again but when using typedef it seems more complex? Because I can not do this typedef int (*FuncPtr)(); FuncPtr = malloc(7);

Comment: `FuncPtr *yourVarName = malloc(7);` works. typedef creates a type, not a variable.

Comment: ok thx i updated the code, but int result = cFunc(); does not seem to compile then saying it is not a function?

Comment: might want to use `typedef int (FuncPtr)();` instead of `typedef int (*FuncPtr)();` so you can put the * in the definition.. imo pointer typedefs which include the `*` are kind of confusing

Answer (score 1):

Well, it certainly is not the best way to include machine code into your C program. Use inline assembly. Since you metnion Ubuntu, I will mention that **gcc** is perfectly able to do that.

See http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html for a start.